# In a C char array that is filled with hex values what would the length be?

Tags: c, arrays

If you have:

```
unsigned char data[] = {0x00, 0x02, 0xEE};
```

Would the length be 3 or would the hex values be representative of two or more bytes and thus equal out to something like 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array is of type `unsigned char[]`, therefore the values it contains are (as big as) `unsigned char`s, which should be 1 byte. Since the array contains 3 values, its total size is 3 bytes.

The [`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) operator can help you figure this stuff out:

```
unsigned char data[] = {0x00, 0x02, 0xEE};

int main(void) {
  printf("size of array in bytes: %d\n", sizeof data);
  printf("size of single element: %d\n", sizeof *data);
  printf("quotient:               %d\n", (sizeof data) / (sizeof *data));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, and will using the sizeof *data only get the size of an individual element only if it is of unsigned char or will it do that for an individual element of any array type?

Comment: @Stavros_S `sizeof` operator calculates and returns the size of the operand after it. `sizeof *data` evaluates into the size of the `*data`, which is equivalent to `data[0]`, just like `*(data + 1) == data[1]`. More generally `*(data + i) == data[i]`, so yeah, `sizeof *data` will always give you the size of an individual element of the array called `data`, regardless of the type.

Answer (score 2):

One digit (or character) in hexadecimal can be atmost represented by 4-bits.
Since, 0 - F would mean `0000` (0) to `1111` (15).
So your above array will take 3 bytes as each element of `data[]` is represented by one byte (two nibbles).